# Error creating bean with name 'userServicesDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'connectionPool';

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am new to Spring Framework. I am just creating POC to learn Spring Concepts. While implementing the same i am getting below exception while loading of application. Please provide me you suggestions to resolve this.

***"Error creating bean with name 'userServicesDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDbConfiguration' parameter 0"***

**UserServicesDao**

```
package com.pe.dao;

@Component
public class UserServicesDao {

    private DBConfiguration dbConfiguration;


    @Autowired()
    public void setDbConfiguration(DBConfiguration dbConfiguration) {
        this.dbConfiguration = dbConfiguration;
    }

     public List<User> getUser()
     {
         System.out.println("User Services Dao : "+this.toString());
         System.out.println("Connection Info : "+this.dbConfiguration);

        return new ArrayList<User>();

     }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserServicesDao [connection Config=" + dbConfiguration + "]";
    }

}
```

**ConnectionConfig.Java**

```
package com.pe.bean;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component(value ="dbConfiguration")

public class DBConfiguration {

    @Value("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    private String driver;

    @Value("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb")
    private String url;

    @Value("root")
    private String username;

    @Value("root")
    private String password;

    public String getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
    public void setDriver(String driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**Spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd">  

<context:component-scan  base-package="com.pe.controller,com.pe.dao,com.pe.bean" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>        

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp">
    </property>
</bean> 
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

</beans>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">

 <welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>


 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <resource-ref>
      <description>DB Connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/spring</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>

  <listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


  <context-param>

  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:com/predictenergy/bean/dao-config.xml</param-value>

  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

[Click to see Class Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVVWr.png)

It was autowiring before correction if i was doing it through xml. Please refer below xml code i was using before.

```
<bean id ="userServicesDao" class="com.pe.dao.UserServicesDao" autowire="byType">
<property name="dbConfiguration" ref= "dbConfiguration"></property>
</bean>

<bean id ="dbConfiguration" class ="com.pe.bean.DBConfiguration">
<property name="driver" value= "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
<property name="url" value= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"></property>
<property name="username" value= "root"></property>
<property name="password" value= "root"></property> 

</bean>
```

Please guide me with your solution.

Comment: Do not mix Annotation based and XML based configuration

Comment: Are you doing a component scan on `com.pe.bean` package?

Comment: No Yashwanth , Its working now. I just added the qualifier with the bean name.
Thanks..

Comment: Thank you both for your Suggestions.:)